# Microsoft CCI based Obfuscator

Tags: .net, obfuscation, cci

I want to write an .NET obfuscator based on Microsoft CCI library. I found a few obfuscators written with Mono.Cecil, but there are no CCI based. Are there any potential problems with CCI for this task?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No experience with CCI, but all the best to your endeavour to create a CCI based Obfuscator. : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There shouldn't be any issue. CCI is licensed under the [MS-PL license](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/ms-pl.html) making it suitable to be shipped in an open-source or a properietary program. Some people find Cecil easier to use, some other are perfectly happy with the CCI. So nope, there should not b any potential issue.